# How to get PdfString elements with some custom XFont or XBrush from loaded PdfDocument using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, fonts, pdfsharp

I need to select some strings when i load PdfDocument.
And it must be loaded only if it is red or if it's font-size equals 26, etc.
Can i do it with pdfSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFsharp was not made for this task.
Here you can find user-supplied code that extracts text from a PDF file:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=1603#p1603
Checking color and font size must be added to the code.